# ¿Puedo reemplazar el nombre estático de un método por uno pasado como argumento a una función?

Tags: javascript, react-native, function

Originalmente en mi proyecto tengo dos bloques de código que se repiten casi en su totalidad, por lo que quisiera saber si es posible, a través de una sintaxis determinada, crear una función para unificarlos que reciba un método como argumento. Por ejemplo:

**BLOQUE 1**

```
navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
                const action = e.data.action;
        
                e.preventDefault();
        
                Alert.alert(
                'Discard changes?',
                'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
                [
                    { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
                    {
                    text: 'Discard',
                    style: 'destructive',
                    onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(action),
                    },
                ]
                );
            });
```

**BLOQUE 2**

```
navigation.removeListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
                const action = e.data.action;
        
                e.preventDefault();
        
                Alert.alert(
                'Discard changes?',
                'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
                [
                    { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
                    {
                    text: 'Discard',
                    style: 'destructive',
                    onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(action),
                    },
                ]
                );
            });
```

**FUNCIÓN DESEADA**

```
const StatusNavigation = (statementArg) => {
        navigation.statementArg('beforeRemove', (e) => {
            const action = e.data.action;
            e.preventDefault();
            Alert.alert(
              'Discard changes?',
              'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
              [
                { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
                {
                  text: 'Discard',
                  style: 'destructive',
                  onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(action),
                },
              ]
            );
        });
    }
```

Luego, en mi proyecto llamaría a la función como **StatusNavigation('addListener');** o **StatusNavigation('removeListener');** según lo necesite.

Dentro de la función, la expresión *navigation.**statementArg**('beforeRemove' (...)* genera el error *TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...navigation.statementArg...')*

Quisiera saber cuál es la sintaxis correcta para tomar el valor del argumento.

---

**.: SOLUCIÓN IMPLEMENTADA, basada en las ideas sugeridas :.**

```
const StatusNavigation = (statementArg, stateFlag) => {
        setFlagModify(stateFlag);
        navigation[statementArg]('beforeRemove', (e) => { 
            const action = e.data.action;
            e.preventDefault();
            Alert.alert(
              'Discard changes?',
              'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
              [
                { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
                {
                  text: 'Discard',
                  style: 'destructive',
                  onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(action),
                },
              ]
            );
        });
    }
```

Luego desde mi código, simplemente llamo a la función según mi necesidad:

```
flagModify ? StatusNavigation('removeListener', 'false') : StatusNavigation('addListener', 'true')
```

Comment: Al escuchar un evento se ejecuta una función, así que solo tienes que crear una función con el código que se repite y luego esa función pasársela a los escuchadores

Comment: Sí, perfecto, entiendo @Christian. Aún así, si quisiera hacer esto de todos modos, o tal vez aplicarlo a otro tipo de función, ¿se puede hacer?,¿cuál sería la sintaxis correcta?. Por ejemplo: he probado con navigation.{statementArg}('beforeRemove' (...)  y tira error.

Comment: en todo caso es [statementArg]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible, aunque no creo que recomendable en este caso, usando `["metodo_como_string"]` en lugar de `.metodo`

```js
const metodo = "addEventListener";

const boton = document.getElementById("boton")[metodo]("click", (e)=>console.log("evento"));
```

```html
<button id="boton">
click
</button>
```

`navigation[statementArg]('beforeRemove' ...` en tu código.

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
import React from 'react';
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

const useListenner = ( navigation, isremove ) => {
  // Your logic
  function eventHandle(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      Alert.alert(
        'Discard changes?',
        'You have unsaved changes. Are you sure to discard them and leave the screen?',
        [
          { text: "Don't leave", style: 'cancel', onPress: () => {} },
          {
            text: 'Discard',
            style: 'destructive',
            onPress: () => navigation.dispatch(e.data.action),
          },
        ]
      );
  }
  
  return isremove ? navigation.removeListener('beforeRemove', eventHandle) : navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', eventHandle);
}

// usage
// useListenner(navigation, true) // removeListener
// useListenner(navigation) // addListener

export default useListenner;
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Efectivamente Diego y @Emmeus, pude solucionarlo con los corchetes y removiendo el punto luego de _navigation_, en línea con el código que vengo desarrollando.
Diego, tu modo también es válido, y creo que está en concordancia con lo expresado por Christian.
Agradezco a todos por sus aportes. Editaré mi pregunta y colocaré la solución.